# Seudat Mitzvah on a Personal Fast Day

Tags: mitzvah, fast-days, meal-seudah

May a person who accepts upon himself a personal fast eat a seudat mitzvah? For example, if a person finds himself at a bris on the day he accepted to fast, is he able to eat?

Comment: Why would you think it's different than a public fast day?

Comment: I think it could be different from a public fast day because it seems like separating oneself from community during a simcha.

Comment: It may be similar to _taanis b'choros_….

Comment: A personal fast day that overlaps with Yom Tov you still have to fast unless you got it annulled (Hatarat Nedarim) OC 570. Clearly some Seudat Mitzva is no better than a full blown Yom Tov

Answer (score -3):

I am answering the OP, who is not referencing Yom Kippur. Yes, because a seudat mitzvah trumps a fast. There are a number of things that can override a personal decision to fast, such as, health, or even a simchat brit.

Comment: This is wrong .

Comment: @DoubleAA surely one can not make comments such as "This is wrong" without saying why?

Comment: Were I to change a site rule based on this case it would be that you can't make posts saying "this is permitted" without saying why. But I'm not in charge of making rules unfortunately.